# Login to Facebook API with known username and password

Tags: php, facebook

I want to build a script where I am logged in automatically with a PHP script, updates the status or w/e and then logs out. Using Graph API or FQL would be great was it not that I get a nasty pop-up that I need to login and allow the 'application'. I don't want this, I know my own username and password and simply want it to login immediately, do its stuff and log out.

Is this possible with the Facebook API? I don't really like scraping FB but they don't let me much choice though =/

So I want to login through a PHP script immediately to Facebook.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have some user's facebook username+password?! I really, *really* hope it's just your own.

Comment: It's actually my client's. They have a facebook page and want to connect all info on all social media...why is this such a weird thing to want?

Comment: Because using the username/password is not necessary for that. You just need the user to authorize your app and grant it the MANAGE_PAGES permission. Then you can get a page token for his page which you can then use to do things as the page. I know it's a horrible mess that a page administrator needs to authorize the app for his whole account (i.e. access to *all* pages instead of being able to add the app to a page and then get a page token without an administrat or being involved except to install the app) but still better than relying on username/password and emulating a normal client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the fb with email and password but its against fb tos. Check this link `http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/code/290893/facebook-login-with-curl`

If you want offline permission then Recent news from facebook, it doesnot supporting offline permission. :(

`https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/`

Answer (score 1):

nope, it is not possible to login with username/password using the api.

what you can do however is let the user grant the offline permission to your app, then you can achieve a similar effect.
(e.g. i used that to create a simple command line status updater)